# Is it safe to use a class inside the package sun.misc?

Tags: java

For example should I use [sun.misc.IOUtils](http://java-doc.narod.ru/sun/misc/IOUtils.java.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not. It's an internal API and there is no guarantee that it will stay unchanged. Use external libraries.

Answer (score 5):

> The sun.* packages are not part of the
>   supported, public interface. A Java
>   program that directly calls into sun.*
>   packages is not guaranteed to work on
>   all Java-compatible platforms. In
>   fact, such a program is not guaranteed
>   to work even in future versions on the
>   same platform.

[More info here](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html).

Answer (score 2):

No, while this might appear to be fine when running on Oracle/Sun JVMs, it is certainly not the case with JVMs developed by IBM or HP, or any other organization (GNU perhaps, and probably even Apple) that does not provide these classes.

You would realize this only when you have to deploy and run on other environments.

Comment: Just FYI: the Apple JVM is based on the Sun JVM, so it *probably* has this class as well (future JVMs for Mac OS X will be OpenJDK based). The point still stands: it's not safe to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info