# How to get the maximum safest integer of a Double in Java

Tags: java, math

Having in mind that Java's [doubles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) are 
[double-precision floating-point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) numbers.
And the maximum integer without loosing precision is **9007199254740991** or **2<sup>53</sup>-1**

**Is there any clean way of getting this value?** 
For instance, like a constant as in JavaScript's [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Not that I know of. Maybe a `public static final double MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = (insert integer here)`. Hopefully someone else knows more.

Comment: These constants are derived from the properties of IEEE floats and doubles. They do not change between language implementations that use, say, IEEE doubles. You can safely hardcode 2e53 - 1 in your own code and don't need a special constant for it.

Comment: Anything wrong with using `Double.MAX_VALUE` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's the maximum value representable by double, not the largest integer that indicates the range that all integers are representable

Comment: Can someone provide a link here which discusses the theory behind this question, in case someone happens to be woefully ignorant of this (cough cough)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an internal JDK class named [`sun.misc.DoubleConsts`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/DoubleConsts.java) which has some constants that you could use to generate the value you're looking for using the ["accpetable" magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Accepted_limited_use_of_magic_numbers) of `1` and `2`, but it doesn't have the number defined itself.

```
public static long MAX_SAFE_VALUE = 
        sun.misc.DoubleConsts.SIGNIF_BIT_MASK * 2 + 1;

// alternatively
public static long MAX_SAFE_VALUE = 
        Math.pow(2, sun.misc.DoubleConsts.SIGNIFICAND_WIDTH) - 1;
```

However, [relying on a class in the `sun.misc` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304755/is-it-safe-to-use-a-class-inside-the-package-sun-misc) is not a very "clean" approach, so I'd just create my own constant.